# I do not understand why the foreign key constraint does not work on product id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE table dbo.PRODUCTS(

[Product ID] int not null,
[Product name] varchar(20) not null, 
[Min price] decimal(10,2) not null,
[Artist ID] varchar(20)not null,
[genre]  varchar(20)not null,


primary key ([Product ID]),

constraint ARTIST FOREIGN KEY ([Artist ID])
REFERENCES  ARTISTS ([Artist email]),
)


CREATE table dbo.ORDERS_DETAILS(

[Purchase number] int not null,
[Product ID] int not null,
[Total price] decimal(10,2) not null,
primary key ( [Purchase number],[Product ID]),

constraint DF_PRODUCT FOREIGN KEY ([Product ID])
****REFERENCES  PRODUCTS ([Product ID]),**** 
constraint fk_PURCHASE FOREIGN KEY ([Purchase number])
REFERENCES  PURCHASES ([Purchase number]), 
)
```

the error:

> Foreign key 'DF_PRODUCT' references invalid column 'Product ID' in
>   referenced table 'PRODUCTS'.

Can someone help me understand why this returns this error? It does not recognize the product id column from the product table even though the table was created correctly and is working.

Comment: Try removing the ending comma before the closing parenthesis. I created both tables just fine.

Comment: Please show exact code you actually ran. Please turn on as much error reporting as possible. Please read and act on [mcve].

Comment: @WEI_DBA Trailing comma is not relevant, this is acceptable in T-SQL and is often found in generated code.  @Maya I also created the two tables fine, I'm guessing you may have another table called `PRODUCTS` with a different schema besides `dbo.PRODUCTS`. Try `REFERENCES  dbo.PRODUCTS ([Product ID]),` instead.

Comment: @pcdev Totally agree. Maya, try dropping tables before you create them. As pcdev suggests, there could be the same table name but different schema.

Answer (score 0):

Drop tables before creating them again.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects
WHERE type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
AND name = 'PRODUCTS')
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [PRODUCTS]
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects
WHERE type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
AND name = 'ORDERS_DETAILS')
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [ORDERS_DETAILS]
END
```

Then create your tables as expected.